# How does webpack handle multiple files importing the same module React

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have a React app which has many components importing the same modules. Does webpack import each module once for each file requesting it, resulting in duplicate code(in this case each import twice for just the two components)? I'm considering re-writing the components so that child components do not need to require the React modules, but maybe I'm solving a problem that doesn't exist. I'd like to avoid many imports of the same react module if it results in duplicate code.

Component 1

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router";
import ReactLogo from "elements/ReactLogo";

export default class MainMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <ReactLogo type="svg" /> <ReactLogo type="png" /> <ReactLogo type="jpg" />
            <h2>MainMenu:</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>The <Link to="home">home</Link> page.</li>
                <li>Do something on the <Link to="todo">todo page</Link>.</li>
                <li>Switch to <Link to="some-page">some page</Link>.</li>
                <li>Open the chat demo: <Link to="chat" params={{room: "home"}}>Chat</Link>.</li>
                <li>Open the page that shows <Link to="readme">README.md</Link>.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Component 2 importing the same 3 modules.

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router";
import ReactLogo from "elements/ReactLogo";

export default class MainMenu extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <div>
            <ReactLogo type="svg" /> <ReactLogo type="png" /> <ReactLogo type="jpg" />
            <h2>MainMenu:</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>The <Link to="home">home</Link> page.</li>
                <li>Do something on the <Link to="todo">todo page</Link>.</li>
                <li>Switch to <Link to="some-page">some page</Link>.</li>
                <li>Open the chat demo: <Link to="chat" params={{room: "home"}}>Chat</Link>.</li>
                <li>Open the page that shows <Link to="readme">README.md</Link>.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

No, webpack (similar to browserify and other module bundlers) will only bundle it once.

Every react component will get its own scope, and when it requires/imports another module, webpack will check if the required file was already included or not in the bundle.

So no, it will not result in duplicate code. However if you import some external packaged libraries, you may have some duplicate code. In that case, you can use Webpack's Deduplication plugin to find these files and deduplicate them. More info here for that: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#deduplication

Comment: Why then repeating imports in every file?

Comment: Sorry, but i'm working with that and my code is included multiples times. I don't know how fix it. All my files in es6 have a 200kb size (all toghether) and my "bundle" file have 1.3mb @trekforever

Comment: So is React duplicated on each component that imports it?

Comment: Where is feature documented?

Comment: @jrodriguez If your files all have identical code in them but are still separate files they will take up all that space.  If you had one file with all that code and imported it in to 6 other files they would not repeat all that code but instead reference back to the original entry.

Comment: @DejanMilosevic Because each file maintains its own context, it is not aware of what all the other files that are being bundled have inside them or what they do.  It doesn't mean that each file will become bloated with repeating code, webpack takes care of that.