# Bundling js files with webpack class undefined

Tags: javascript, webpack, ecmascript-6

Im bundling together the following files contents:

a.js:

```
class BaseC {
    doIt(){
        console.log(this);
    }
}

class A extends BaseC{
}
```

b.js:

```
class B extends BaseC{
}

var b = new B()

b.doIt();
```

These are bundled in a final app.bundle.js. When running it i get : `"Uncaught ReferenceError: BaseC is not defined"`. This is very odd to me as i can see it as defined first and foremost in the app.bundle.js prior to the rest of the classes as follows:.

```
var BaseC = function () {
    function BaseC() {
        _classCallCheck(this, BaseC);
    }

    _createClass(BaseC, [{
        key: "doIt",
        value: function doIt() {
            console.log(this);
        }
    }]);

    return BaseC;
}();
```

Any clues?

P.S: Im not using the require/import system. I know this is how webpack is normally used but what im doing is providing an array with all the js files i want bundled to webpack using the glob module and expected that with such a simple example, it should work.

Comment: are you exporting *BaseC* class in `a.js` file and importing it in `b.js`?

Comment: thanks for replying. kristaps said the same thing but he thing is, even though exporting/importing works, it SHOULD work without having to do that anyway as its already defined on the app.bundle.js file – George Avgoustis just now   edit

Comment: This has to do with context.  `BaseC` exists in the context of the file `a.js` but not `b.js`.

In order for `b.js` to use `BaseC` it must be imported or required.  Follow kristaps' answer below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does webpack handle multiple files importing the same module React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313662/how-does-webpack-handle-multiple-files-importing-the-same-module-react)

Comment: Have a read of this [stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313662/how-does-webpack-handle-multiple-files-importing-the-same-module-react), the modules will not be duplicated but they are required in the context of files that consume them.

Answer (score 2):

Try exporting the class from a.js:

`export class BaseC { ...`

and importing it into b.js:

`import {BaseC} from './a.js'
...`

Comment: The thing is, even though exporting/importing works, it SHOULD work without having to do that anyway as its already defined on the app.bundle.js file

Comment: i agree. theres gotta be a way to not have to import things all over the place in a simple website...