# Why not add classes to window or global in a namespaced variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, module, es6-class

I am using webpack to transpile/bundle/etc my js files. Im using the import/export syntax ( as opposed to the CommonJS way of require and export.module ). This means i need to import each class and all subclasses of it however many times if i need to use them in the context of a specific script.

**The question:**

Even though classes arent natively supported in js, why do we need to import them all the time? Wouldnt it be easier if ( and im only speaking for classes ) they were available to all scopes?

EDIT: To avoid polluting the global scope one could do something like global.myLibs and be done with that issue. I personally prefix my classes with something unique but this method would serve even those that dont i suppose.

For example:

`window.myClasses` could serve as a container for all my classes. I come from an iOS background where all the classes in a main "bundle", in java i think that would be a "package" are available to everyone. Re-importing the class itself doesnt seem like it serves any purpose.

See here:
[Why do i need to import modules everytime in webpack bundle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251371/why-do-i-need-to-import-modules-everytime-in-webpack-bundle)

and here: [Bundling js files with webpack class undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247545/bundling-js-files-with-webpack-class-undefined)

Comment: Where's your Node tag.

Comment: Using webpack you can split out commonly used modules into a separate file.

Comment: please review my answer on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47251371/why-do-i-need-to-import-modules-everytime-in-webpack-bundle/47257985#47257985

Answer (score 0):

Adding things in the global scope can lead you to naming conflicts. What if you created a class named `Node`, add it to global scope by doing `window.Node = Node` ? You lose the reference to the browser's global Node object.

You can argue that you will never use names that are already used for global objects. But now, what if in a year or so, a new object is added to the spec with the same name as one of yours, and you want to use it alongside your own object ? You have to make a choice, or rename your own object. This is not future proof.

Importing the same module in every module that uses it is a best practice. Because by doing it, you never pollute the global scope. Don't be afraid that it imports the code of this module n times in your final bundle. Webpack imports it only one time, then uses a reference to the module everytime you are importing it.

See these resources :

- [JavaScript Modules: A Beginner’s Guide](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc) by Preethi Kasireddy on Medium
- [Eloquent Javascript Modules chapter](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html)

Comment: Sure this makes sense but it comes with a huge downside. I need to keep importing every class or subclass model or anything at all every time all the time if i need it in multiple places and that doesnt feel right. maybe not adding it to the global scope directly but adding it to global.MyLibs would solve that issue. And it would feel a lot more like programming in other languages where you've got access to the classes. 

Whats the flaw with this logic? :/

Comment: I don't understand "class or subclass". If a class extends another class, you don't have to import all the chain everytime.

Comment: you do if you want to use the superclass's static methods. I like how im downvoted but nobody except you can comprehensively answer this.

Comment: Can you edit your question by adding a minimal code example please ? I'm very curious about your question and I think it is interesting.