# remove duplicate sass imports (webpack)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass

I have a big project with a lot of sass files (and all of them import a main sass file with some varibales and classes).

I belive you all know the problem that the file that i am import in all of my css files is duplicate in the main css file after buiding the project.

i tried using ExtractTextPlugin options and plugin that called OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin, and i didnt find solution for this problem.

Here is the plugins array in my webpack prod config:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({
          filename: "styles.css",
      }),
      new OptimizeCssAssetsPlugin({
          assetNameRegExp: /\.optimize\.css$/g,
          cssProcessor: require('cssnano'),
          cssProcessorOptions: { safe: true, discardComments: { removeAll: true } },
          canPrint: true
      }),
```

anyone know the solution for this problem?

thank you!

Comment: your answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313662/how-does-webpack-handle-multiple-files-importing-the-same-module-react

Comment: @Er.Ellison i am importing the main sass file inside every sass file that i have in the project, so i dont think that this is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Less users are in luck! @import (reference) does exactly what it that:

Use @import (reference) to import external files, but without adding the imported styles to the compiled output unless referenced.
However in Stylus /Sass, there is no direct way to import by reference:

The closest you will get is a silent class / placeholder. These work a little different to how LESS and reference work, you can read more on them here: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/extending-placeholder-selectors-with-sass

Refernce: [Rerernce](https://codeburst.io/lets-talk-import-in-preprocessors-f97a4e685131)

Comment: i found this solution and it dosn't seems to work: https://paul.wellnerbou.de/2015/05/18/avoid-multiple-imports-of-the-same-scss-file-with-sass/ you know this solution?