# Unable to implement Materialize-CSS initialization scripts with NextJS

Tags: materialize, next.js

I'm using [Materialize CSS](https://materializecss.com) to style a web app I'm working on. Am building the app using NextJS with ReactJS. I have already styled the navbar using the classes defined in the Materialize CSS file. However, I'm unable to implement the responsive sidebar functionality using the prescribed initialization script [as instructed on the Materialize website](https://materializecss.com/sidenav.html).

My Navbar component (./components/Navbar.js) looks like this:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import $ from 'jquery';

class Navbar extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.props = props;
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
      var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (

      <Fragment>
        <nav>
          <div className="nav-wrapper blue">
            <Link prefetch href='/'>
              <a href="/" className="brand-logo">Project Coco</a>
            </Link>
            <a href="#" data-target="slide-out" className="sidenav-trigger"><i className="material-icons">menu</i></a>
            <ul id="nav-mobile" className="right hide-on-med-and-down">
              <li>
                <Link prefetch href='/'>
                  <a>Home</a>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
                <Link prefetch href='/about'>
                  <a>About</a>
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </nav>
        {/* Sidenav markup */}
        <ul className="sidenav" id="slide-out">
          <li>
            <Link prefetch href='/'>
              <a>Home</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link prefetch href='/about'>
              <a>About</a>
            </Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Navbar;
```

As is obvious, this functionality (sidebar) needs JQuery. So I already have it added via `yarn` and am invoking it using `import $ from 'jquery'`. But upon running, it throws an error saying **sidenav is not a function**.

I even tried entirely doing away with JQuery and just going for the vanilla JS version of the initialization script in `componentDidMount`:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.sidenav');
    var instances = M.Sidenav.init(elems, options);
  });
```

But this time, although no error, the functionality still refuses to work and clicking on the hamburger menu doesn't trigger the sidenav, which it should.

The entire code repo is up on [Github](https://github.com/amitschandillia/coco) for reference and the prototype app is live at [schandillia.com](https://github.com/amitschandillia/coco). Any solutions?

P.S.: It seems the problem is that the initialization code in `ComponentDidMount` gets executed before MaterializeCSS.js (being called as an external file), on which it depends. Any work around this could be a potential solution, although that's just an assumption.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to import materialize-css into your component. Sadly, if you try to do `import 'materialize-css'` you'll get a `window is undefined` error. This is because Next.js is universal, which means it executes code first server-side where **`window` doesn't exist**. The workaround I used for this problem is the following:

Install materialize-css if you haven't:

```
$ npm i materialize-css
```

Import materialize-css into your component **only if `window` is defined**:

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.$ = $;
    window.jQuery = $;
    require('materialize-css');
}
```

Then, in your `componentDidMount` method:

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav();
}
```

So your component looks like this:

```
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';
import Link from 'next/link';
import $ from 'jquery';

if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    window.$ = $;
    window.jQuery = $;
    require('materialize-css');
}

class Navbar extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.props = props;
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
        $('.sidenav').sidenav();
    }

    render() {
        return (
              <Fragment>
                <nav>
                    ...
                </nav>
                {/* Sidenav markup */}
                <ul className="sidenav" id="slide-out">
                    ...
                </ul>
              </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar;
```

Sources: [Next.js FAQ](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/wiki/FAQ#i-use-a-library-which-throws-window-is-undefined) and [this issue](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/3773).

Comment: Thank you for an excellent solution, Raúl. Just one last question if you don't mind: If I import materialize like this in multiple components, will it increase my JS payload? I mean, will each component add an additional copy of the library to the rendered page?

Comment: No, it won't. Webpack will handle that for you:
"Every react component will get its own scope, and when it requires/imports another module, webpack will check if the required file was already included or not in the bundle." Hope this helps!
Source: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33313662/how-does-webpack-handle-multiple-files-importing-the-same-module-react

Comment: Please doest it works with CSS module ? Before I go on my boilerplate

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:-

- _app.tsx

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import '../styles/globals.css';

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return <Component {...pageProps} />;
}

export default MyApp;
```

- index.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

const Index = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const M = require('materialize-css');
    M.toast({ html: 'worlds' });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='container'>
      <h1>hello</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Index;
```